# How to consume a webservice in Typo3?

Tags: web-services, typo3

Is there extensions for that ? For exemple for SOAP webservice ?
Or we have to do specific developpement ?

Answer (score 0):

There are already some solutions. (Maybe you can specify in detail what you need exactly?)

**RSS:** rss2_import.
That is a simple way to automatically display remote content on your site. tt_news is required. One direction only. 
http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/rss2_import/1.0.0/view/

**SOAP:** nf_nusoap.
Very basic, last update 01/2003. I don't have any experiences with this extension. However, it may be tweaked for your needs. 
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/nf_nusoap/current/

**JSON:** Didn't find anything.